# How do I setup Selendroid in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, selenium, selendroid

I cannot figure out how to setup selendroid in Visual Studio and I cannot find any documentation to help me out.

I am trying to do something like:

```
IWebDriver driver = new SelendroidDriver();
```

I understand I need the Android SDk installed but how do I actually call the code to start the browsing session in my C# code?  I cannot find any Visual Studio nuget package for selendroid or any DLL to add.

Answer (score 1):

When looking for information on this I came across this post describing unit tests with C# and Selendroid. YMMV.

http://pritamsen.wordpress.com/2014/04/11/selendroid-c-code-with-nunit-runner-to-run-on-device/

Comment: where is `TouchCapableRemoteWebDriver()` defined?  I cannot get this code to work.

Comment: Please find code for TouchCapableRemoteWebDriver() at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selendroid/B3VpbXtV2r0

Answer (score 1):

The step I was missing is that there is no library for selendroid, you just use the remoteWebDriver